# How to delete records from a table having IN,Group By and Having with more than 1000 records in IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

Data needs to be deleted from a table using IN clause but the records in IN clause are more than 1000. The Query has Group by and Having too and there are too many columns in the table! So I am unsure how to do it using a TEMP table.

The query is:

```
  DELETE * FROM test WHERE order_num IN( 
  select order_num 
  FROM test
  WHERE TO_DATE (mod_dt) BETWEEN TO_DATE ('11-JUN-15') AND TO_DATE ('17-JUL-15')
  AND REGION = 'AK'
  GROUP BY order_num
  HAVING COUNT(order_Num) > 1) ;
```

Comment: What exactly seems to be the problem?

Comment: The number of records in IN clause are more than 1000, so it gives error!

Comment: `mysql, sql-server, oracle` they are all different product, tag your question with the correct one you are using.

Comment: I dont think no of rows will cause into the error. Just give it a try and go for it

Comment: `TO_DATE ('11-JUN-15')` is missing its format mask. You shouldn't ever use `TO_DATE()` without one as that means you're still relying on the default NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter to decide how to convert the string into a date - not a good thing! Also, years have 4 digits, not 2 (Y2K wasn't *that* long ago.... was it?!). You should be using something like `TO_DATE ('11/06/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')` instead.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? I have never heard that there is a sub-query max record limit. What exactly is the error message you get when you run the query?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need Group by and having clauses, do you?

You can use common table expression:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT top 1000 * FROM test WHERE order_num IN( 
      select order_num 
      FROM test
      WHERE TO_DATE (mod_dt) BETWEEN TO_DATE ('11-JUN-15') AND TO_DATE ('17-JUL-15')
      AND REGION = 'AK') )

delete *
from CTE;
```